# ggplotly hover only working on borders of multipolygon

Tags: r, ggplotly

I am using ggplotly instead of plotly as ggplotly loads much faster in my shiny app. However, the hover only works on the border of the counties in my map, as shown in the image.  I want to be able to hover in the center of the county and have the hover informatoin show up. Here is the code I am using:

Does anyone know how to get around this, using ggplotly? Plotly is too slow. Thank you in advance!

```r
   plot <- ggplot() +
     geom_sf(data = nc_counties, aes(fill = PoundsDistributed)) 
   
   ggplotly(plot)
```

[image]

I tried using the tooltip = "" in the ggplotly call, but that did not help.

Comment: What happens if you do: `ggplotly(plot) %>% style(hoveron="fills")`